# What does # (hash symbol / pound sign) mean in type signatures?

Tags: casting, f#, symbols, type-signature

What does `#` mean in type signatures like `seq<#seq<'a>>` compared to just `seq<seq<'a>>` ?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx and specifically http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233198.aspx.

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstandings about the title, the hash symbol is called the pound sign in the US and Canada. So that's why, if you wondered.

Comment: @BentTranberg i changed the title.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is called *flexible type*. The short summary is that `#type` means *any* type that is inherited from `type`. So, in your concrete example `seq<#seq<'a>>` will be a sequence of any collections containing `'a` values.

When calling a function, F# automatically casts concrete types to interfaces - so for example, you can call a function taking `seq<'a>` with array `'a[]` as an argument. However, this does not work when you have array of arrays - because `'a[][]` only implements `seq<'a[]>` but not `seq<seq<'a>>`.

For example, the following two functions return list of lengths of nested sequences:

```
let f1 (s:seq<seq<'T>>) = [ for i in s -> Seq.length i ]
let f2 (s:seq<#seq<'T>>) = [ for i in s -> Seq.length i ]
```

But only the second one can be called on lists of lists:

```
[ [1]; [2;3] ] |> f1
// error FS0001: The type 'int list list' is not 
// compatible with the type 'seq<seq<'a>>'

[ [1]; [2;3] ] |> f2
// val it : int list = [1; 2]
```